# ネットワーク図を書くためのjavascriptのライブラリ

Tags: javascript

先ほど、Yahoo!知恵袋とQiitaにも投稿したんですが、こちらの方が詳しく話を聞けそうなので、投稿しなおしました。

下記のような、ネットワーク図を書く最適なライブラリを教えてください。

言語はJavaScriptを考えています。それよりも簡単に書ける言語やライブラリがあればそれも教えていただければ嬉しいです。
目的は、ログデータの可視化をしたいと思っています。

ログデータの中身は複数の施設を人物が移動した履歴のデータです。

データは２点間同士の関係のデータで以下のようになっています。
下記のようなデータ群があります。

・出発点
・到着点
・出発時刻

このようなデータが２０万件ほどあります。

このデータをもとに、ネットワーク図のノードを施設、エッジを人物の移動を表し、
人物の移動をアニメーションで作りたいです。（出発時刻をもとにした時間経過の。）

あと、その２点間を通った人数（重複含めた）も可視化させたいです。（エッジの矢印の太さや色などで。）

JavaScriptで動かすのであればブラウザ上で動けばいいので動画ファイルにする必要などはありません。

一応、vis.jsとSetTimeoutを併用しようとおもいましたが、難しくなりすぎると思ったので質問しました。

ご回答よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 1):

Processingのjsモジュールはいかがですか？
http://processingjs.org/

あとは流行っているD3.js
http://d3js.org/

webアプリケーションにこだわらなければProcessing単体でもいいかもですね。

インタラクティブな可視化ができておもしろいですよ。